# How do I get request body in phoenix?

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to build a phoenix application, and I handle a POST request. I want to get the request body, and I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do it.

Doing some reverse engineering I got to the following code:

```
defmodule MyApp.Controllers.Pages do
  use Phoenix.Controller

  def post(conn) do
    {_, {_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, body, _, _, _, _, _, _}} = conn.adapter
    text conn, "#{inspect body}"
  end
end
```

with routing:

```
defmodule MyApp.Router do
  use Phoenix.Router

  post "/test", MyApp.Controllers.Pages, :post
end
```

There must be a better way, no?

Expected behavior:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:4000/test -d 'this is a test'
$ "this is a test"
```

Answer (score 6):

I am using Phoenix version 0.6.1 and I was not able to get the approaches above to work. I have though found the following to work:

```
defmodule MyApp.MyController do
  use Phoenix.Controller

  plug :action 

  def login(conn, _params) do
    {:ok, data, _conn_details} = Plug.Conn.read_body(conn)

    # ...
  end
end
```

The request body is returned in data. Not sure if this is the "official" way to get the request body, but thought I would share it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `read_body` function.

> This function reads a chunk of the request body up to a given :length.
>   If there is more data to be read, then {:more, partial_body, conn} is
>   returned. Otherwise {:ok, body, conn} is returned. In case of an error
>   reading the socket, {:error, reason} is returned as per
>   :gen_tcp.recv/2.

[Reference](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#read_body/2)

Answer (score 1):

I just pushed out Phoenix 0.2.5 with the ability to easily access the request body. Plug 4.4 was just released to support `collect_body(conn, "")`. This function is imported within the context of your Phoenix Controllers, so you should be able to simply get the entire body as a string by using `collect_body(conn, "")`. Please give that a shot and open up a Github issue if you're unable to get it working.

https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/master/lib/plug/conn.ex#L355-L394

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot test Phoenix 0.2.5, since it my project uses `amnesia`, which breaks on elixir 0.14.0...

Answer (score 0):

I found this inside the tests in [elixir-lang](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/blob/12a3613af1ef82338a4c211d9d3c7c11ee8a1d1e/test/plug/adapters/cowboy/conn_test.exs#L147):

```
defmodule MyApp.Controllers.Pages do
  use Phoenix.Controller

  def post(conn) do
    body = read_req_body(conn)
    text conn, "#{inspect body}"
  end

  defp read_req_body({:ok, buffer, state}, acc, adapter) do
    read_req_body(adapter.stream_req_body(state, 100_000), acc <> buffer, adapter)
  end

  defp read_req_body({:done, state}, acc, _adapter) do
    {acc, state}
  end

  defp read_req_body(%{adapter: {adapter, state}}) do
    {body, _} = read_req_body({:ok, "", state}, "", adapter)
    body
  end
end
```